# Image scrolling back and forth using transform animation

Tags: css

Let's say we have a container and image, both with different unknown sizes and proportions.
I want to fit image inside the container, save it proportions, and scroll it back and forth so it you can see it whole.

I achieved it by setting image as background cover and using background-position animation:

**html:**

```
<div class="animated-background-image"></div>
```

**css:**

```
.animated-background-image {
  background-image: url(http://images.apple.com/v/home/dd/images/gallery/macbookpro_large_2x.jpg); 
  width: 100%; height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 100% 100%; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a6uc8ruL/

But animating background-position is heavy and not very smooth compared to animating transform position.

So I want to translate image up and down(or left and right if it is landscape) from 0px to (parent_size - image_size).
How do I calculate this value or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Accidently came to a partial solution: to animate position and translation of an  element, same when centering image vertically.

```
from { top: 0%;   transform: translateY(0%); }
  to { top: 100%; transform: translateY(-100%); }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a6uc8ruL/5/

But as there are two opposite properties being animated, image glitches back and forwards eventually. So it is required to animate only one translate property.
And the annoying part - this approach requires different animations for vertical and horizontal scroll.